# Finding a fixed polynomial under the multiplicative inversion automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Can anyone find a polynomial $f ∈ ℚ\left(X+\frac{1}{1-X} + \frac{X-1}{X}\right) ⊆ ℚ(X)$ that is fixed under the automorphism $(X ↦ \frac{1}{X})$? $f = X+\frac{1}{X}$ would be nice, but I don't know how to check if it's in the given (sub)field.

(**End game / context:** find $f ∈ \mathbb{Q}(X)$ s.t. $\mathbb{Q}(f) = \mathbb{Q}\left(X+\frac{1}{1-X} + \frac{X-1}{X}\right)^{(X ↦ \frac{1}{X})}$.)

Comment: Do you actually mean addition here, so that the field you're talking about is $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{x^3-3x+1}{x^2-x})$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Every element of that field is fixed under $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{1-x}$, because applying this transformation shifts the three summands cyclicly, so this is a necessary condition.  Test $x+\frac{1}{x}$ to see if this works.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that comment means, I mean to calculate $\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ and see that it isn't equal to $x+\frac{1}{x}$.  But once you've done that, can you even yet say that your field is closed under $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}$?  Like is $\frac{\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x}+1}{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x^3-3x^2+1}{x-x^2}$ in the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting
$$g(x)=x+\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x-1}{x}$$
it's easily verified that
$$g(x)+g\!\left({\small{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)=3$$
hence letting $h(x)=g(x)\bigl(3-g(x)\bigr)$, we get
$$h(x)=g(x)\,g\!\left({\small{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$$
so $h$ satisfies the required conditions.

Comment: You make it look so easy ;). Can we say anything about $[\mathbb{Q}(g) :\mathbb{Q}(h)]$? I would like it to be 2 :p

Comment: @Jos van Nieuwman: From the equation $g^2-3g+h=0$, we get $[\mathbb{Q}(g):\mathbb{Q}(h)]\le 2$, but then since $h(x)=h(1/x)$ and $g(x)\ne g(1/x)$, it follows that  $\mathbb{Q}(h)$ is a proper subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(g)$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(g):\mathbb{Q}(h)]=2$.